# Drupal - fbconnect:Facebook PHP library not found

Tags: facebook, drupal

i've a problem with fbconnect module on drupal 7.
I installed the module, i activated it and, as readme suggest, i uploaded facebook-php-sdk in site/all/libraries/facebook-php-sdk and now it looks like site/all/libraries/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php, but the status report still output that:

> "Facebook PHP sdk  Fbconnect : Facebook PHP library not found. See
>   README.txt".

I don't find a solution, any idea?
Please sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this module, this is in my opinion the best one for Facebook authentication in Drupal 7.
http://drupal.org/project/fboauth

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with:

```
\xampp\htdocs\yoursite\sites\all\libraries\facebook-php-sdk\src\
```

Look at your `s` in `site\`.